# Out of the box command for the total number of slides in a frame?

Tags: beamer

Is there a command `\inserttotalslidenumber`, similar to, for example, `\inserttotalframenumber`?

I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The title (\insertslidenumber/\inserttotalslidenumber)}
   %
   \only<+->{Some content.}
   \only<+->{Some more content.}
\end{frame}
```

To generate "The title (1/2)" and "The title (2/2)" on the respective slides.

**Edit:**

There is currently no out-of-the-box command for this. See samcarter's response below for a way to make the calculation.

Comment: In addition, look for `frametitle continuation`in the beamer manual.

Comment: I had already found that answer, but was wondering if beamer defines a more "standard" way of doing so. Is the answer basically "no"?

Comment: **(1)** Then next time maybe refer to the related question that you already found - this saves others time. It's your 17th question - you are not a newbie anymore :). **(2)** I am afraid that there is no more standard way.

Comment: So every time one asks a question, they also need to mention the other 200 links they already checked?

That answer is rather far from what I was looking for. Given the plethora of other `\insert` commands available, one would not expect to have to make the calculations mentioned there...

Comment: @dow You should add all the information you already have to you questions to help the people willing to help you!

Comment: Well, the linked question describes what you want. I did not find other questions like that. And yes, I also would have hoped for a out-of-the-box solution. I did not find one and also used the answer that is provided in the linked question as you can see by my comment there.

Comment: I guess the way I phrased the question deviates from what I intended to say. I was specifically looking for an out-of-the-box solution, as opposed to "a way to get the total number of slides in a frame".

Shall I update the question, so that the answer is a clear "no" to anyone else looking?

Comment: It's your question, but sure, add that there's no out-of-the-box command. And consider accepting and/or upvoting the provided answers since it solves your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\insertslidenumber` was recently added to beamer, but you still need toc calculate the total number of slides in the frame.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\newcounter{cont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\inserttotalslidenumber}{    \setcounter{cont}{\beamer@endpageofframe}%
    \addtocounter{cont}{1}%
    \addtocounter{cont}{-\beamer@startpageofframe}%
    \arabic{cont}%
}
\makeatother

\title{title}
\author{author}

%%%%%
\begin{document}   

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The title (\insertslidenumber/\inserttotalslidenumber)}
   %
   \only<+->{Some content.}
   \only<+->{Some more content.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding *\insertslidenumber*! Good to know

Comment: Sam, I have updated the question to reflect what I had in mind. Would you mind adding a sentence along the lines of "there is no out-of-the-box way to do that as of now", preferably at the beginning of your response? Thanks!