# Beamer: navigation bullets for current frame

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames, bullets

I have one frame that has three slides (I don't know how to call them, frame, slide...) as follows:

[image]

Each of the three slides are part of the same frame and were created using `\pause`.

I would like to create navigation dots to indicate in which of this slides we are in:

[image]

If the current frame has only one slide, I would like to display just one dot. If the current frame has `n` slides, then I would like `n` dots.

Is this possible?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}

\begin{frame}{Single Frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}

\begin{frame}{Multi slide frame}
    \textbf{First slide}. I would like to have 3 dots at the bottom indicating the navigation of the current frame. \pause

    \textbf{Second slide}. The  second dot should be filled now.\pause

    \textbf{Third slide}. Now the third dot should be filled.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.3}

\begin{frame}{Single Frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424568/out-of-the-box-command-for-the-total-number-of-slides-in-a-frame

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2):

Your MWE does not have any footline, but you can add the following code to whatever footline you use:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{cont}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \setcounter{cont}{\beamer@endpageofframe}%
  \addtocounter{cont}{1}%
  \addtocounter{cont}{-\beamer@startpageofframe}%
  \ifnum\thecont>1%
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., \thecont}{%
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}%
        \ifnum\i=\insertslidenumber%
                ~\usebeamertemplate{mini frame}%
            \else%
                ~\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current section}%
            \fi%
        }%
    \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1.1}

\begin{frame}{Single Frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.2}

\begin{frame}{Multi slide frame}
    \textbf{First slide}. I would like to have 3 dots at the bottom indicating the navigation of the current frame. \pause

    \textbf{Second slide}. The  second dot should be filled now.\pause

    \textbf{Third slide}. Now the third dot should be filled.
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1.3}

\begin{frame}{Single Frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. It seems your code does exactly what I want, however I cannot make it work. I get an error, do you know what could be?

Comment: @user171780 Which error do you get? Does this happen with the MWE from my answer or in your real document? If its the later, I need to see a small document that reproduces the error.